# É possível atribuir a mesma URL para mais de um controller?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, annotation

Estou tentando utilizar AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url : urlN, // <<- "/log"
    type: "post",
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = json;
    }

setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000);
```

para atualizar, a cada 'X' tempos, somente uma parte de uma pagina HTML (`<div>`). O problema é que, eu não conseguia pegar o conteúdo do meu arquivo, pois, o meu controller retornava o nome da minha view, oque resultava nisso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de vários tentativas, descobri que eu não podia passar o nome da view pelo meu controller, e sim um objeto do arquivo que eu gostaria de acessar. Sob conselhos, adicionei a notação @ResponseBody para que o retorno do método seja automaticamente escrito na resposta para o cliente. O problema é que desse jeito, eu "perco" a minha view e o único retorno exibido é o conteúdo em si. Ou seja, meu problema se inverteu..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
         //String  - View
    public Log jsonLogContent(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
        if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
            try {
                fileNumberLines(log);
                log.setPathFile(logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename());
                log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), log.getPathFile()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        }

        model.put("path", logsDir);
        model.put("log", log);
        model.put("currentPage", "logs");
        model.put("root", root);
       //return "log"; - View
        return log;    // Obj
    }
```

**Minha duvida:**

Existe alguma forma de contornar essa situação? Fazendo com que seja possível 
 duas URL's para o mesmo controller? Ou uma forma para que a view seja carregada 
 primeiro e em seguida o objeto?